# CakePHP4 not showing or logging fatal error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have deployed my app to the server, and on refreshing the home page I get the generic "An error has occurred " page with no details.

There is no corresponding entry in the error.log
There is not corresponding entry in /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log

Looking at phpinfo, i have
display_errors: on
display_startup_errors: on
log_errors: on

app.php has debug = true

I can't find any information about the error anywhere.  How can I force Cake to show or log the error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run  `composer install` ? Have you checked apache/nginx logs ?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to error500.php

```
<div class="" style="padding: 20px">
  <?= debug($error->getMessage()) ?>
      <br/>
      <strong>File</strong>
      <?= h($error->getFile()) ?>
      <br/>
      <strong>Line: </strong>

   <?=  stackTrace() ?>
    <?= $this->element('exception_stack_trace');?>
  </div>
```

This showed the error, which was of course lack of write permissions for the appache group for error.log.

Comment: and of course then hide the debg stuff because it 's a bit of a security issue and looks bad to show that stuff